# How to bind multiple pair of selector:event in jQuery ON method

Tags: jquery-selectors, jquery

I m using jQuery 1.7+ latest [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method, but failed to implements, please help me.

working [`Fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/xkeshav/UnJE4/).

basically here is my

#### HTML

```
<ul id="sortByRight" >
     <li id="1"><a href="javascript:void(0)">List</a></li>
     <li id="2"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Photo</a></li>
     <li id="3"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Map</a></li>
</ul>

<select name="sort" id="sort"  >
   <option value="1">Recommended</option>
   <option value="2">Price: low to high</option>
   <option value="3">Price: high to low </option>
   <option value="4">Newest</option>
</select>
```

#### jQuery code

```
$(document).on('change click', 'ul#sortByRight,select#sort', function() { 
               selectedOption = $('select#sort').val();
               whatToShow = $(this).attr('id');
               alert('selectedOption:'+selectedOption+'whatToShow:'+whatToShow);
              }
);
```

now I havebelow problems/queries.

- can we bind one event with one selector i.e. above function should be called
    **EITHER**  `on change of selectbox` **OR**  `on click of ul`.
- how to set `data` argument in `.on` method. I have tried like below

  `$(document).on('change click', 'ul#sortByRight,select#sort',

  { selectedOption : $('select#sort').val(), whatToShow : $(this).attr('id') } ,

  function(){console.log('selectedOption:'+selectedOption+'whatToShow:'+whatToShow);}

  );`

  but get an error that `selectedOption is not defined.`
- can we write something like this `$(this, li);` because I need the **id of li** not the **id of selectbox**.
- if there is  any other optimized solution ( using function like `live` or `bind` ), then please tell me.

Thanks A Lot.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% clear on what you actually want to do, but one thing doesn't make much sense. You want to send the ID of the LI when the select box is changed. Which LI? The last LI clicked? You need to store the state of the active LI so that you can send it in the ajax request if the select box is changed.

Perhaps something like this:

```
$('select#sort').change(function() {
    processAjax();
});


$('ul#sortByRight > li > a').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('ul').find('li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).closest('li').addClass('active');

    processAjax();
});

function processAjax() {
    selectedOption = $('select#sort').val();
    whatToShow = $('ul#sortByRight').find('.active').attr('id');
    alert('selectedOption:' + selectedOption + 'whatToShow:' + whatToShow);
}
```

[or check out the jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UnJE4/3/)

Comment: +1, for the help. i want to shorten the jquery events. i know the above method already.
and yes i want the is of current selected(clciked) ` li `

Comment: i want to use `.on` method not the old `.change` method

Comment: You don't need to bind both events using the same selector. When selecting an item from the drop down list, you **don't** want the code to select the active LI to run. When clicking an LI, you don't need to bind it to the change function. You could chuck a conditional in the event to check which element called it, but seriously, you don't need to do it.